# JavaScript get keys from object

Tags: javascript

I have the following object as you can see on console line 85.
[image]

And I have the following JavaScript code

```
      for (var key in orderObject) {
        if (!orderObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    
        var obj = orderObject[key];
        for (var prop in obj) {
            if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
              continue;
    
            console.log((prop + " = " + obj[prop]));
        }
      }
```

And you can see what this piece of code prints on the console on line 97.

What I want to achieve is first of all to access the keys, `seller accepted the order` , `seller delivered the order` etc. I can do for example `Object.keys(orderObject)` and it will print those keys. But I want to achieve so such manner that I get the key and the value for each item in that object. Ideally something like `seller accepted the order,  1602709200` since I do not care about nanoseconds.

How can I achieve it?

I am mostly stuck because I treated it like an array an tried `for(), forEach()` but these cannot be used here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(orderObject)) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${value.seconds}`);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this for get the keys and values

```
For(const [key, value] of Object.entries(orderObject)){
   console.log(key,value)
}
```